# My Script is outputting "False"

Tags: powershell

I am sorry the code is too long and it wont let me post without putting more details but its so long Id have to make a huge paragraph of details

Here is the link to powershel script its from technet.microsoft :

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/LAPSpass-Standalone-LAPS-7fa3a5aa#content

Comment: please post the script

Comment: Sorry the code is to big to post and it wont let me without putting lots of details but this is where I got it from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/LAPSpass-Standalone-LAPS-7fa3a5aa#content

Answer (score 0):

Seeing False (or any other value being written on output) would be a return from some method that returns some value, you can see them in your code ending with () or a variable within the (). 
PowerShell will write the value to the screen unless you are assigning it to a variable.
Example below would return False by default on $form.ShowDialog();

```
$form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "This is a Form"
$form.Width = 360
$form.Height = 300
$form.MaximizeBox = $false
$form.MinimizeBox = $false
$form.FormBorderStyle='FixedSingle'
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$groupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$groupBox.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,50)
$groupBox.text = "This is a groupbox"
$groupBox.Add_Click({
    $form.Close();
});

$form.Controls.Add($groupBox);
$form.ShowDialog();
```

To fix your problem, you can either add [void] in front of any methods to not return an output to screen like

```
[void]$form.ShowDialog();
```

Or, assign a variable

```
$result = $form.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: hey thanks a bunch what I had was a few of these: `$ComputerNameInput.Focus()` I put `[void]` in front of that and it now stops saying false. But there are alot of `$ComputerNameInput.Focus()` code in the script but I had had to amend one of them and it stopped outputting false

Comment: I wouldn't assign it to a variable unless you intend to use it. IMO `$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null` or `$form.ShowDialog() > $null` is preferable.

Comment: @Raziel casting to `[void]` is not an assignment, and it's actually slightly faster than piping to `Out-Null` or redirecting to `$null`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I was referring to his second example. Didn't know about the performance difference though.

Comment: @Raziel [Check this out](https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/610deb873a96f331039d) (you may have to bump the Iterations count up to ~1m if you want to see significant diff)